# Heroku bundler update removes installed gem and causes my app deploy to fail compile

Tags: ruby, heroku, bundler

I have a running ROR Heroku app and I upload code changes regularly. in my recent upload, Heroku changed their bundler version from 2.3.10 to 2.3.25 and now my app deployment fails on compile because one of the gems is removed in the Heroku process...
I only did minor changes in css so I'm sure the reason is not caused by code changes...
no changes were done in gemfile and gemfile.lock as well.

the app compiles and runs with no problems on local dev machine.

you can see in the attached images the changes between the logs of the last successful deploy and the recent failed one. it looks like for some reason the new bundler is removing mini_portile2 (2.6.1) and this causes my compile to fail because some other gem is dependent on it.

mini_portile2 (2.6.1) appears in gemfile and gemfile.lock so I cannot understand why it is removed.

Log of the last successful deploy:
[Log compare 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLeMm.jpg)

```
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/ruby
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Installing bundler 2.3.10
-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.7.1
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.3.10
       Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
       Using rake 13.0.6
       Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
       Using i18n 1.8.10
       Using minitest 5.14.4
       Using tzinfo 2.0.4
       Using zeitwerk 2.4.2
       Using activesupport 6.1.3.2
       Using builder 3.2.4
       Using erubi 1.10.0
       Using mini_portile2 2.6.1
       Using racc 1.5.2
       .....
       Bundle complete! 39 Gemfile dependencies, 132 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups 'development' and 'test' were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
       Bundle completed (0.88s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Installing node-v16.13.1-linux-x64
-----> Installing yarn-v1.22.17
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
```

Log of the recent failed deploy:
[Log compare 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Fw7.jpg)

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-18 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/ruby
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.3.25
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:
remote:        Your app was upgraded to bundler 2.3.25.
remote:        Previously you had a successful deploy with bundler 2.3.10.
remote:
remote:        If you see problems related to the bundler version please refer to:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#known-upgrade-issues
remote:
remote:
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.7.1
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.3.25
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
remote:        Using rake 13.0.6
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
remote:        Using i18n 1.8.10
remote:        Using minitest 5.14.4
remote:        Using tzinfo 2.0.4
remote:        Using zeitwerk 2.4.2
remote:        Using activesupport 6.1.3.2
remote:        Using builder 3.2.4
remote:        Using erubi 1.10.0
remote:        Using racc 1.5.2
               .....
remote:        Bundle complete! 39 Gemfile dependencies, 131 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups 'development' and 'test' were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
remote:        Bundle completed (0.69s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Removing bundler (2.3.10)
remote:        Removing mini_portile2 (2.6.1)
remote: -----> Installing node-v16.18.1-linux-x64
remote: -----> Installing yarn-v1.22.19
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     /tmp/build_5db96fd8/vendor/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:86:in `block in materialize': Could not find mini_portile2-2.7.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I have tried deleting gemfile.lock and re-creating it.
I have tried changing the version of mini_portile2 to a newer version ... I keep getting the same failed log file.
I'll really appreciate any help to fix this issue.

Comment: "suddently my app deployment failed on compile.." - maybe it makes sense to add the original problem too? (text please, [no screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557))

Comment: done, thanks. it is also described in the next paragraph.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Added log examples inline. Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue just w/ `mini_portile2-2.8.0`. @idb were you able to figure it out?

Comment: Any updates on this? I've just encountered this on an app I work on.